# how to get param in method post spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using spring mvc. And I can't get param from url when method = post. But when I change method to GET, so I can get all param.

This is my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8080/cms/customer/create_customer" id="frmRegister" name ="frmRegister" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class ="iptRegister" type="text" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" value="" />
    <input class ="iptRegister" type="password" id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword" value="" />
    <input class ="iptRegister" type="text" id="txtPhone" name="txtPhone" value="" />

    <input type="button" id="btnRegister" name="btnRegister" value="Register" onclick="" style="cursor:pointer"/>
</form>
```

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/create_customer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String createCustomer(HttpServletRequest request, 
        @RequestParam(value="txtEmail", required=false) String email, 
        @RequestParam(value="txtPassword", required=false) String password, 
        @RequestParam(value="txtPhone", required=false) String phone){

    ResultDTO<String> rs = new ResultDTO<String>();
    rs.setStatus(IConfig.SHOW_RESULT_SUCCESS_ON_MAIN_SCREEN);
    try{
        Customer c = new Customer();
        c.setEmail(email);
        c.setPassword(password);
        c.setPhone(phone);
        customerService.insert(c);
        rs.setData("Insert success");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        log.error(ex);
        rs.setStatus(IConfig.SHOW_RESULT_ERROR_ON_MAIN_SCREEN);
        rs.setData("Insert failure");
    }
    return rs.toString();
}
```

How can I resolved this?

Comment: How are you setting those parameters in the form in your JSP? Can you show some more of that code?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

1. Spring annotations will work fine if you remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

   ```
   @RequestParam(value="txtEmail", required=false)
   ```
2. You can even get the parameters from the `request` object .

   ```
   request.getParameter(paramName);
   ```
3. Use a [form](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib) in case the number of attributes are large. It will be convenient. [Tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-handling-forms/) to get you started.
4. Configure the Multi-part resolver if you want to receive `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

   ```
   <bean id="multipartResolver"
     class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
       <property name="maxUploadSize" value="250000"/>
   </bean>
   ```

Refer the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch16s08.html).

Comment: I would recommend using a form for binding the parameters if there are more than a few of them. Spring's `@RequestParam` annotation is a convenience mechanism which definitely reads better than doing `request.getParameter` throughout the code. But +1 for the `MultipartResolver` bit.

Comment: In case of using form tag, doesn't matter to have the bean fields names in the html code?

Comment: The multipartResolver didn't work for me. I still get the same error. Do I need to do anything else besides add the bean definition? Do I need to add something to my controller class/method to use it?

Answer (score 8):

It also works if you change the content type

```
    <form method="POST"
    action="http://localhost:8080/cms/customer/create_customer"
    id="frmRegister" name="frmRegister"
    enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

In the controller also add the header value as follows:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create_customer", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

Answer (score 8):

When I want to get all the **POST** params I am using the code below,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ViewForResponseClass update(@RequestBody AClass anObject) {
    // Source..
}
```

I am using the **`@RequestBody`** annotation for post/put/delete http requests instead of the `@RequestParam` which reads the GET parameters.

Comment: Thanks, This is what I wanted...!!

Answer (score 7):

You should use `@RequestParam` on those resources with method `= RequestMethod.GET`

In order to post parameters, you must send them as the request body. A body like JSON or another data representation would depending on your implementation (I mean, consume and produce `MediaType`).

Typically,  *multipart/form-data*  is used to upload files.