# How would I parse a string in @RequestBody?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

Here is my HTML Page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Sports</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Configuring Database for MSell Application</h1>
        <form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/MSellApp/msellapp/DBConfig/changedb" enctype="text/plain">
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>Database to be Used</td>
                    <td><select name="selectDB">
                            <option value=0>Sports and Outdoor</option>
                            <option value=1>Fashion</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my spring rest service.

```
@RequestMapping("/DBConfig")
@RestController
public class DBConfigController {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DBConfigController.class);


    @Autowired
    DBConfig dbc;

    @RequestMapping(value="/changedb",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes="text/plain",produces="text/plain")
    String changeDB(@RequestBody String db){
        logger.info("DB Selected :- " +db);
        System.out.println(db);

            if(db.equals("selectDB=0"))
                dbc.sessionFac="sports";
            else
                dbc.sessionFac="fashion";


        return dbc.sessionFac;


    }
}
```

That String comparison is always getting failed.I am using spring rest API. I'm just finding it too difficult to crack why the string comparison always fails even though the print statement prints the same "selectDB=0". Can Somebody tell me why ?

Comment: Try checking whether there is any heading/trailing whitespace in `db`.

Comment: No there's no space. I tried trimming it and then comparing.

Comment: do you get an exception?

Comment: No exception. It just executes else part normally.

Comment: i just tried the same config on my machine and everything prints out correctly

Comment: Yeah you're right. There was a heading/trailing whitespace. It worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you use `@RequestParam("selectDB")` as method parameter? You would even be able to use an `int` parameter in that case. You don't need to specify the `enctype` btw. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/17964841/525036