# JSON -> Entity with Spring Data JPA / Spring REST

Tags: java, json, jackson, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I have a Foo class and a Bar class:

```
@Entity
public class Foo extends BaseEntity {
    private Long id;
    private String foo;
}

@Entity
public class Bar extends BaseEntity{
    private Long id;
    private String bar;
}
```

And a `@Controller`

```
@Controller
...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo/{foo}")
    public void foo(@PathVariable("foo") Foo foo) {
...
```

With Spring Data JPA and Sprint REST, I'm able to pass e.g. Foo as an id in the URL and automatically get a Foo object via the built-in **domain-class-converter** http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.basic.domain-class-converter:

This works fine. But in some cases I want to **POST data to the controller via JSON** instead of url parameter

```
{
    foo : {id : 42},
    bar : {id : 123},
}
```

Is it possible to automatically get that similarly completely loaded from JPA (and not only initialized with the id)?

I tried @RequestBody but that only initializes the values that are given by the request without loading the entity from the db.

Comment: Are you asking about sending JSON data using POST or how to parse given JSON to the object representation? For first check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964841/how-to-get-param-in-method-post-spring-mvc

Comment: I'm asking about a @Controller receiving JSON

Comment: so this answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36849152/1653268

Comment: That answer won't load the JPA entity, but initialize it only with the posted data (the id only). I would like to get the complete object as Jackson does it with @PathVariable

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. Spring Data REST uses GET method for finding data and POST for creating new instances. See 5th chapter of documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: Maybe it could be done via registering a ConditionalGenericConverter like here https://candrews.integralblue.com/2015/07/spring-id-to-entity-conversion/