# Spring post method "Required request body is missing"

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, post

```
@PostMapping(path="/login")
public ResponseEntity<User> loginUser(@RequestBody Map<String, String> userData) throws Exception {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.login(userData));
}
```

I have this method for the login in the UserController. The problem is when i try to make the post request for the login i get this error:

```
{
"timestamp": "2018-10-24T16:47:04.691+0000",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.scd.model.User> org.scd.controller.UserController.loginUser(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws java.lang.Exception",
"path": "/users/login"
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Hi! what is the body you are passing to your API?

Comment: Do i need to pass the email and password in Body?

Comment: Depends, you can do on both ways, se my anwer :D

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have to pass that as JSON in your body, if it's a POST request.

[image]

Comment: Change Media type `Text` to `JSON` as I have done in the picture above.

Comment: for some case (happened to me), it must be added headers information.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar issue, was getting this error in my Spring Boot service

> HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing:...

My issue was that, when I was making requests from **Postman**, the **"Content-Length"** header was unchecked, so service was not considering the request body.

Answer (score 9):

This is happening because you are not passing a body to you server.
As can I see in your screenshot you are passing email and password as a ResquestParam.

To handle this values, you can do the following:

```
@PostMapping(path="/login")
public ResponseEntity<User> loginUser(@RequestParam("email") String email, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
     //your imp
}
```

In order to accept an empty body you can use the `required` param in the RequestBody annotation:

```
@RequestBody(required = false)
```

But this will not solve your problem. Receiving as RequestParam will.

If you want to use RequestBody you should pass the email and password in the **body**.

Comment: To receive RequestParam in POST you can refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964841/how-to-get-param-in-method-post-spring-mvc

You can also pass the data through the body, which makes sense too, since it is a post request.

Comment: The **@RequestBody** for the Type doesn't work, but actual Type parameters work? Wonder why?

Comment: this solution works for me, make sure on postman you're sending the post with the parameters as well

Answer (score 4):

If it's still not working, try adding additional information `UTF-8` in Headers.

key : `Content-Type`
value : `application/json; charset=utf-8`

For my case, I must adding `UTF-8` in Headers.

Comment: Same case with me

Answer (score 3):

You need to send data in Body as JSON

```
 { "email":"email@email.com", "password":"tuffCookie"}
```

Comment: @lonut click  raw

Comment: @lonut click on text combo and change to json

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was poorly defined JSON that I sent to my REST service.

Attribute that was suppose to be an object, was in my case just string:

Changed from:

```
"client" = "",
```

to:

```
"client" = { ... },
```

In my case String did not add additional information about value in different format.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding such header `'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` solves the issue.
The servlet do have the @RequestBody part.
I assume Spring will need such header to form the post body

Answer (score 0):

If it is  XML Request Try importing  jackson-dataformat-xml.jar to your project it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i was using @RequestBody in a @GetMapping api and for that reason happened to face the issue "Required request body is missing", hope nobody do this crazy thing because doesn't make sense at all but if someone like will do, here is a quick solution to fix it :D

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering the same issue, turns out that my JSON body was not valid. I mindlessly added some Java style comments which made it invalid.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).