# Getting unexpected token : Postman post request

Tags: java, spring, post, request, postman

I'm want to make a POST request to my REST API but I'm getting the error that 
The REST API is made in Spring
I have an unexpected token :

POST Request Call :

```
http://localhost/users/load
```

Java Code:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/load")
public User load(@RequestBody final User user){
    userRepository.save(user);
    return userRepository.findByName(user.getName());
}
```

User Class:

```
@Entity
public class User {
private Long id;
private String name;
private String username;
private String password;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long getId(){
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id){
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public String getUsername(){
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username){
    this.username = username;
}

public String setPassword(){
    return password;
}

public void getPassword(){
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

JSON data:

```
{
    "name": "John", 
    "username": "randomUsername", 
    "password": "Password123!"
}
```

Postman:
[image]

Error:

```
There was an error in evaluating the test script:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

I expected that the request should pass but it didn't

Comment: check you test block in postman looks like a test is failing. This error has nothing to do with spring.

Comment: @GrinishNepal the error I'm getting {
    "timestamp": "2019-09-04T19:51:51.787+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Required request body is missing: public com.spring.timelybackend.models.User com.spring.timelybackend.controllers.UserController.load(com.spring.timelybackend.models.User)",
    "path": "/users/load"
}

Comment: You might need to ignore the id from the entity so maybe `@JsonIgnore` from jackson might help you. The error is straight forwd wrong request model which is user.

Comment: Please also post the screenshot of how you sent the POST request in Postman.

Comment: @LHCHIN check updated version

Comment: The answer was found [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52974330/spring-post-method-required-request-body-is-missing/52974492)

Comment: @Tom van den Bogaart That's why I requested you to provide the screenshot of Postman. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are adding request body in tests tab,

Request body must be in body tab then select raw, and paste you json also add header in headers tab `content-type` : `application/json`

Please check this [sample](https://s3.amazonaws.com/postman-static-getpostman-com/postman-docs/58960775.png)

Postman [ref](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests/#raw-request)

Tests tab is for writing JavaScript code to assert if body is what i expected in order to test my app.