# i could not test the Rest post in SoapUI which has @RequestBody in the method, Any help appreciated

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, soapui

```
@RequestMapping(value="/postdata", method= RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
public String postdata(@RequestBody String test, @RequestBody String data) {
        logger.info("password reset Request " + requestbody.get("test"));
        logger.info("password reset Request " + data);
        return "Hello";
}
```

Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public java.lang.String mail.controller.EmailNotifictaionController.postdata(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)]

My Input in the SOAPUI is
{
"test":"my",
"data":"god"
}

Comment: looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52974330/spring-post-method-required-request-body-is-missing

Comment: I am looking for SOAPUI,

Comment: soap UI is just another tool to submit http requests. you're probably not including the JSON in your http request body

Answer (score 2):

You are using two `@RequestBody` which is not the correct way as one request can only have one request body.

You can either combine both the request bodies into single request body or you can build a wrapper class having both the `test` and `data` variables like:

```
public class Body {
    public String test;
    public String data;
    // You can also keep them private and have getters/setters.
}
```

and use this class in the API method argument

```
@RequestMapping(value="/postdata", method= RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
public String postdata(@RequestBody Body body) {
        logger.info("password reset Request " + body.test);
        logger.info("password reset Request " + body.data);
        return "Hello";
}
```

You can try this way, it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I was so far trying with multiple @RequestBody, now using a Single wrapper class